# visual studio shell F# keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio

I've started using F# with the visual studio shell and I like the capability to be able to send lines to fsi by highlighting them, but the alt+Enter shortcut is really awkward and I would be much happier with this being on shift+Enter.  (mainly since shift+ up/down arrow is select lines already)

Does anyone know how to change this?  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you know you can right-click too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the keyboard mappings within Visual Studio.  If you go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, you'll see a window like the image below.

In order to check existing bindings, place the cursor in the "Press shortcut keys:" box and hit "Shft+Enter".  You'll then see any potential conflicts in the drop-down box as shown.

In the example below, I'm searching through Global, which means shortcuts for anything in the application.  You can switch it to be just the console or whatever you like.

Once you're happy with the shortcut you want to use, you need to select the command from the window containing all of the Action.* lines and then press Assign.

[image: Keyboard Mapping Options in Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: @chucktaylor So does Frank's answer unless I'm missing something. If you'd asked him a followup question we wouldnt need to use a picture to tell a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't mean to be trite, but have you tried mapping the key?

So for F# Interactive I see Alt+Enter mapped to:

ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewMultiselectProjectreferencesItems.Properties

Have your tried mapping Shift+Enter (or whatever) to that command?

Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard

You should be able to get it all working from there.